# If condition#1 AND Application.Match Then

Tags: vba, excel, match

I want to check for two conditions:

1. If `Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1) <> ""`
2. If the `Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1)` can be found in `Tabelle8.Range("A:A")`

In case one of them is not fulfilled I want it to jump to the next `i`.

Therefore, I'm using `Application.Match` for the second condition and the code is the following:

```
If Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1) <> "" And Application.Match(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), Tabelle8.Range("A:A"), False) Then
```

But the Run-Time Error '13' "Types Incompatible" occurs. Does someone know why and how I can make this one work? :)

Below the whole code:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim lastrow2 As Long
    lastrow2 = Tabelle3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set myrange2 = Tabelle8.UsedRange

    For i = 2 To lastrow2
        If Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1) <> "" And Application.Match(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), Tabelle8.Range("A:A"), False) Then
            Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 19) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), myrange2, 3, False)
            Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 20) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), myrange2, 4, False)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `Not IsError(Application.Match(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), Tabelle8.Range("A:A"),0))`

Comment: Data type incompatible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this code:

```
Sub TestMe()        
    Debug.Print CBool(Application.Match("Something", Range("A:A"), False))    
End Sub
```

It prints  `True` on the immediate window, although there is no string "Something" on the first column of your worksheet. Thus in your case, `Application.Match(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), Tabelle8.Range("A:A"), False)` will always be evaluated to `True` and this is not how it should be.

Consider some check for errors like `IsError(Application.Match(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), Tabelle8.Range("A:A"), False))`, which would be `True`, in case that the value cannot be found.